# Why custom NIO Selector Provider?

Tags: java, selector, nio

Does anyone know why would we ever need a custom selector provider in java NIO. Is there anyone who has ever used a custom selector provider and why would you do that?

Comment: I don't really see any point. However, some people might want to create a more optimized `Selector` for whatever reason. I honestly have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mock implementation.

It can be quite useful to write unit tests against code which uses NIO. Otherwise, it could be tricky to simulate various kinds of network failure.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote one to provide SSLSocketChannels and SSLServerSocketChannels (and SSLSelectors ...). I can also imagine writing one to provide proxying, as java.net.Proxy and the like aren't supported at all in java.nio.

Comment: Please, do you have an example somewhere ? I may need a custom provider to provide SerialPortChannels.

Comment: @ThibautD. Why do you need an example? Just extend the SPI class and implement the abstract methods.

Comment: It's not clear how I'm suppose to implement functions like   openServerSocketChannel or openPipe... I need to "extend" the default provider, maybe not implementing a full one.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing JDK 16 (Early Access) provides SelectorProviders for `epoll` and `poll`. Linux kernel 5.1+ provides `io_uring` which is claimed to be more performant and more flexible than `epoll`.

Being able to use a custom SelectorProvider via system property or via ServiceLoader makes it possible to use io_uring even with old JVMs.

I wasn't able to find any open source implementation so far!